# How to create twig files content type specific in Drupal8?

Tags: theming, 8

I have created a content type in Drupal 8. How should I write content type specific twig file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use this file for specific content type "node--{content type machine name}.html.twig".
Please check this url for [Twig Template naming conventions](https://www.drupal.org/node/2354645).